# icon in task bar will not change when winform is published

Tags: winforms, publish

I have a winform app running on .net 4.  When a certain condition happens, the icon running in the task bar changes from ping_logo to ping_logo_red.  (the icon i'm talking about is the one that shows up when you run an application.  You click on it and it will restore the windows to the screen or minimize it)  The way that the icon is changing is as follows.

I added the ico files as Resources.  In the code I change the resource being used

```
  Me.Icon = My.Resources.ping_logo_red
```

Here is the thing.  This works when I run the exe from my machine from the solution bin/release folder.  When I publish this and install it from the published location, the icon does not change.

In the publish tab under the project both ping_logo.ico and ping_logo_red.ico are included in the publish status.

what have I not done that is keeping the icon from working in the published app. I've tried to uninstall the app and install it fresh but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

thanks
shannon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using ClickOnce to publish your application then you need to set the icon property in the properties window of your project.

1. Right click your project -> Properties
2. Go to application tab
3. Select your icon file towards the bottom.

Another idea is changing the CopyToOutput property of your .ico file to "Copy Always" or "Copy If Newer".